# what is permutation invariant sequence space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

what is permutation invariant sequence spaces? And why $c_{00}$ is the smallest permutation invariant sequence space?

Comment: More context is needed to be sure.  Are you given a fixed group of permutations?  Are these applied to coordinates of a finite dimensional vector space, or (as the term sequence hints) to a space of infinitely many coordinates per vector?  I would imagine the trivial "zero" space would be the smallest invariant sequence space,  so perhaps $c_{00}$ means that, or it might mean the space of constant sequences (smallest nontrivial invariant subspace under the group of all permutations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence space is a space of sequences.  In this case I think you're talking about a vector space, each member of which is a sequence ${\bf x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$ of real numbers (or complex, if you prefer complex scalars).
A permutation $\pi$ of the natural numbers $\mathbb N$, i.e. a one-to-one function from $\mathbb N$ onto $\mathbb N$, acts on such sequences by 
$\pi {\bf x} = (x_{\pi(1)}, x_{\pi(2)}, x_{\pi(3)}, \ldots)$.  The space is invariant under permutations if $\pi {\bf x}$ is in the space whenever $\bf x$ is.

Notations differ, but I suspect $c_{00}$ is the space of sequences that have only finitely many nonzero terms.  This is invariant under permutations ($\pi {\bf x}$ has the same number of nonzero terms as $\bf x$).  It is not really the smallest permutation invariant sequence space (that would be $\{\bf 0\}$), but it is the smallest that contains, say, the sequence $(1,0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: THX. bro. your are good